# git fetch fills disk with tmp_pack files, never completes

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a Jenkins server trying to pull a large (1.7GB) Git repository. The users of the repository have done naughty things, like putting big tar files in it as well as copies of other Git repositories. Jenkins never finishes its "branch indexing" task for the repository. Looking at the repo on disk, it fills up with large tmp_pack files in $JENKINS_HOME/caches/git-XXX/.git/objects/pack/. If I check out the repo myself, it's 1.7GB; but Jenkins' copy is 140GB because of all these tmp_pack files.

Edit: I should have mentioned more about my environment. I'm running Jenkins inside Kubernetes, using the Kubernetes plugin to spawn pods as Jenkins slaves. The master Jenkins runs in a pod with a Persistent Volume on NFS. And I'm using Jenkins' Multibranch Pipeline, so all the logic is in `Jenkinsfile` in the root of the repo.

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: Why can't it check out the repository?

Comment: how are you trying to checkout the repository using jenkins. Please mention the steps in question to get to know the details.

Answer (score 5):

I found the problem for my case. Jenkins has a global Git timeout of 10 minutes, but my repository takes more than 10 minutes to clone. [JENKINS-20387](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20387) has instructions for changing the timeout. You set `JAVA_OPTS=-Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git.timeOut=60`. In my case, I had to also change it for the pod configuration for the slaves.

Comment: I should mention the tmp_pack files appear to be the result of partial clones that were interrupted when they hit the 10 minute timeout.